# Email received but image not displaying?

Tags: php, html, subdomain

In my demo project, I used the email functionality for new register user into the system. For receive mail, used one kind of HTML page with all mail sent details of the respective user. For image added the path of the website like "http://abc.input.com/assets/image/welcome.png". Stored the same template body details in the database too. The path is recorded the same as the set path. But when I got the mail banner image not displaying and on inspect mail body image path showing one extra dot-like "http://abc..input.com/assets/image/welcome.png". That extra dot will create a problem to display image. Is it regarding any email agent-specific issue? Please share any suggestion. I have tried to provide a set of all  related HTML tag but not working.

`<img src="http://abc.input.com/assets/image/welcome.png" style="height: 175px; width: 560px;" alt="welcome">`

Comment: Most, if not all, email clients strip out images as they can be used to track users. You cannot control this.\

Comment: @JohnConde to be frank, only Outlook does that afaik.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Way more than Outlook does it. It's pretty much standard practice across the board. Gmail started to strip trackers and use their own code to display the images but that's about it for email providers allowing support.

Comment: Yes, that's one is correct. But I used the two more image like social icons with the same server path. Both social icons display properly in the mail except the banner image not display.

Comment: @JohnConde ah, of course, enlightened am i. TBird, Apple Mail app, iOS mail, Android mail, etc ... all must also strip trackers and display with their own code. Shoulda have known :) That being said, outlook also blocks, even when i send banner image as b64 encoded png, (ie no network call involved, no tracking possible)

Answer (score 0):

I' do some minor changes in `<img>` source tag with renaming the image name with a small case and added the `<anchor>` tag with href attribute. Now the image is showing properly when I got the email from the client.